# C# Regex Split - How do I split string into 2 words

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have the following string:

```
String myNarrative = "ID: 4393433 This is the best narration";
```

I want to split this into 2 strings;

```
myId = "ID: 4393433";
myDesc = "This is the best narration";
```

How do I do this in Regex.Split()?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the format always like this? If so, you can split the string at the second white-space. No regex needed.

Comment: If it is a fixed format as shown, use [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match.aspx) with Capturing Groups. Split is useful for a repeating sequence; this is not.

Comment: Yes, the pattern is always the same across the board. How do I capture the groups using Regex.Match?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a fixed format as shown, use [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz.aspx) with Capturing Groups (see [Matched Subexpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#matched_subexpression)). Split is useful for dividing up a repeating sequence with unbound multiplicity; the input does not represent such a sequence but rather a fixed set of fields/values.

```
var m = Regex.Match(inp, @"ID:\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)\s+");
if (m.Success) {
    var number = m.Groups[1].Value;
    var rest = m.Groups[2].Value;
} else {
    // Failed to match.
}
```

Alternatively, one could use Named Groups and have a read through the [Regular Expression Language quick-reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

Comment: Sorry one more thing with the string pattern is that:

Sometimes it could be "NEWID: 493333 New ID Description".

So ID part could be any word.

Comment: @JKK The above regular expression will still match that - because `Regex.Match` is *not anchored* by default. If you do wish to add anchoring, look up the `?` Quantifier and non-Capture Groups.